# Increasing n-body program performance using OpenMP

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

My goal is to increase the performance of a code that simulates the n-body problem.

This is where the time is to be calculated. The two functions that need to be parallelized are the ***calculate_forces()*** and the ***move_bodies()** functions but since the loop control variable ***t*** is a double I cannot have a ***#pragma omp parallel for*** statement there.

```
t0 = gettime ();
  for (t = 0; t < t_end; t += dt)
    {
      // draw bodies
      show_bodies (window);

      // computation
      calculate_forces ();
      move_bodies ();
    }

  // print out calculation speed every second
  t0 = gettime () - t0;
```

The two functions ***calculate_forces()*** and ***move_bodies()*** with the respective directives that I used are the following:

```
static void
calculate_forces ()
{
  double distance, magnitude, factor, r;
  vector_t direction;
  int i, j;
 #pragma omp parallel private(distance,magnitude,factor,direction)
 {
   #pragma omp for private(i,j)
   for (i = 0; i < n_body - 1; i++)
    {
      for (j = i + 1; j < n_body; j++)
        {
          r = SQR (bodies[i].position.x - bodies[j].position.x) + SQR (bodies[i].position.y - bodies[j].position.y);
          // avoid numerical instabilities
          if (r < EPSILON)
            {
             // this is not how nature works :-)
              r += EPSILON;
            }
          distance = sqrt (r);
          magnitude = (G * bodies[i].mass * bodies[j].mass) / (distance * distance);

          factor = magnitude / distance;
          direction.x = bodies[j].position.x - bodies[i].position.x;
          direction.y = bodies[j].position.y - bodies[i].position.y;

          // +force for body i
        #pragma omp critical
         {
          bodies[i].force.x += factor * direction.x;
          bodies[i].force.y += factor * direction.y;

          // -force for body j 
          bodies[j].force.x -= factor * direction.x;
          bodies[j].force.y -= factor * direction.y;
          }
        }
    }
 }

}
static void
move_bodies ()
{
  vector_t delta_v, delta_p;
  int i;
 #pragma omp parallel private(delta_v,delta_p,i)
 {
 #pragma omp for 
 for (i = 0; i < n_body; i++)
    {
      // calculate delta_v
      delta_v.x = bodies[i].force.x / bodies[i].mass * dt;
      delta_v.y = bodies[i].force.y / bodies[i].mass * dt;

      // calculate delta_p
      delta_p.x = (bodies[i].velocity.x + delta_v.x / 2.0) * dt;
      delta_p.y = (bodies[i].velocity.y + delta_v.y / 2.0) * dt;

      // update body velocity and position
      #pragma omp critical
      {
      bodies[i].velocity.x += delta_v.x;
      bodies[i].velocity.y += delta_v.y;
      bodies[i].position.x += delta_p.x;
      bodies[i].position.y += delta_p.y;
      }
      // reset forces
      bodies[i].force.x = bodies[i].force.y = 0.0;


      if (bounce)
        {
          // bounce on boundaries (i.e. it's more like billard)
          if ((bodies[i].position.x < -body_distance_factor) || (bodies[i].position.x > body_distance_factor))
            bodies[i].velocity.x = -bodies[i].velocity.x;
          if ((bodies[i].position.y < -body_distance_factor) || (bodies[i].position.y > body_distance_factor))
            bodies[i].velocity.y = -bodies[i].velocity.y;
        }
    }
}
```

The values of bodies.velocity and bodies.position are changed in the move bodies function, but I couldn't use a reduction.

There is also a checksum function to calculate if the calculated checksum is equal to the reference checksum. That function looks like this:

```
static unsigned long
checksum()
{
  unsigned long checksum = 0;

  // initialize bodies
  for (int i = 0; i < n_body; i++)
    {
      // random position vector
      checksum += (unsigned long)round(bodies[i].position.x);
      checksum += (unsigned long)round(bodies[i].position.y);
    }

  return checksum;
}
```

This function uses the previously calculated values of bodies.position.x and bodies.position.y which were calculated in the move_bodies function hence the reason why I used a critical block while calculating those value which didn't seem to yield a correct answer. Can anyone give me some insight on where I am going wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: non of the variables defined at the top of `calculate_forces ()` need to be placed there. Place them closest to the first point at which they're needed (or if you're using c99, at the place you assign them). Because of this you forgot to declare `r` private.

Comment: @Lanting I was given the code and told to add the OpenMP directives. So that means I shouldn't change anything , but you are correct I forgot to declare as private.

Comment: Is the question about performance (as the title indicates)? Then you must report specific performance results. Or is the question about correctness - then you must report specific expectation and how the actual result differs. In any case, please include a [mcve]. Or is the question already solved by Lanting's comment?